# MicroSD permissions & move applications to microsd

Tags: sd-card

I am using Android version 9.

I was using my mobile with an microSD, formatted as external storage. 
Most applications were moved to microsd/running from there.
So I decided to buy a faster one; I copied all files to my PC (just copied all files loosing all extra attributes).

Then I formatted the new one as external storage and I copied all files.
But it crashed (DoA) after a few hours. During troubleshooting I accidentally formatted as internal but didn't work (obviously). Luckily no data was lost as it wasn't writable.

Now I have again a working microSD formatted as external.
I copied all files to it. However, all application are not capable of moving to microsd and use the internal storage.

Any idea how to make "move to sd card" button available again ?

Thank you

Comment: If you switch back to the old card is the button usable again? Hence is it a system problem or a problem with the new card?

Comment: Unfortunately, the old card was formatted a few minutes before the first card got unreadable.

Comment: i doubt you was able to move apps to MicroSD Card as portable storage at any time. format MicroSD Card as [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) then android will let you move apps (migrate data)

Comment: If I format the microsd as internal storage it will not be readable from any another device. But my old microsd was readable and I could see data from apps in there.

Probably android 9 does not support that anymore.